# Pass data parent to child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I can not render the options of a select dynamically depending on the type of select. What is the problem?

The console.log show with messsage "true" but no charge HTML element

```
/*Call to component*/
<SelectContainer type={1}/>

/*Component*/
import React from 'react';
const SelectContainer = ({type}) => {
let option = [];

if (type === 1) {
    option.push = (<option value="#">asdf</option>)
    console.log("true"+option);        
}else if (type === 2) {
    option.push = (<option value="#">1</option>);        
    option.push = (<option value="#">2</option>);
    option.push = (<option value="#">3</option>);
    console.log("false"+option);
}else{
    console.log('nooo')
}
return (
    <select className="selectContainer">
        {option}
    </select>
);
}

export default SelectContainer;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's try to change your code like this :

```
/*Call to component*/
<SelectContainer type={1}/>

/*Component*/
import React from 'react';
const SelectContainer = ({type}) => {
let option = [];

if (type === 1) {
    option.push(<option value="#" key={0}>asdf</option>)
    console.log("true"+option);        
}else if (type === 2) {
    option.push(<option value="#" key={0}>1</option>);        
    option.push(<option value="#" key={1}>2</option>);
    option.push(<option value="#"key={2}>3</option>);
    console.log("false"+option);
}else{
    console.log('nooo')
}
return (
    <select className="selectContainer">
        {option.map((item) => {
           return item
        })}
    </select>
);
}

export default SelectContainer;
```

you must put your variable to `map()` function, it will be loop your options component, and don't forget use `key`. it will be show a warning if you don't set that, maybe it can help you :)

Comment: One question Rizal Sidik , exist other way to do this example? For example... without array?

Comment: Why would you need to map, it also will return an array

Answer (score 0):

Since your `option` variable is an array, you have to map it out with `map`. Like this:

`{ option.map(item => item) }`

Also your `.push` operation is not correct.

It should be: `option.push(<option value="#">1</option>);` instead of assignment with `=`.

Comment: Mmm not found :-(

Comment: updated my answer. your `push` was an assignment to option, not pushing into array. Now it works as expected :)

Comment: So... if not use array for 'save' various HTML elements... How would i do?¿ with operator '+'?